# Suite Talk API : Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] Your connection has timed out. Please log in again

Tags: php, web-services, netsuite, suitetalk

I am using php toolkit 2019_2 and have configured TBA with the consumer key, secret, token key and token secret. 
However, every time I run a script I get an error as below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] Your connection has timed out. Please log in again. in
>    in /home/user/public_html/order/PHPToolkit/NSPHPClient.php:338 Stack trace: #0 /home/user/public_html/order/PHPToolkit/NSPHPClient.php(338): SoapClient->__soapCall('search', Array, NULL, Array) #1 /home/user/public_html/order/PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php(155113): NSPHPClient->makeSoapCall('search', Object(SearchRequest)) #2 /home/user/public_html/order/samples/saved_search.php(13): NetSuiteService->search(Object(SearchRequest)) #3 {main} thrown in /home/user/public_html/order/PHPToolkit/NSPHPClient.php on line 338

Tried with the sample codes provided with toolkit. Still the same.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does this error occurs immediately? Or after 30 seconds e.g. If so, try to increase your execution timeout (php.ini).

Comment: Hi John, the error occurs immediately. The execution time is set to 500.

Comment: Maybe your webservice is not started?